# Selenium - unable to click on "Unread"

Tags: selenium

I am not sure why i am not able to click on Unread? I am able to locate the element but selenium cannot click.

[image]

Comment: What's your code and the exception?

Comment: Are you saying that you are not able to click 'Unread' in your Yahoo mail?

Comment: We can't help you if you don't share your code and html

Comment: I have posted my code below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve it by hovering over the element first. Thank you so much

```
element_to_hover_over = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@id='smartviews-app-list']/li[@data-id='simple-unread']")

hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element_to_hover_over)
hover.perform()
time.sleep(2)
self.click(30, "xpath", "//ul[@id='smartviews-app-list']/li[@data-id='simple-unread']")
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work to click on Unread link:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@id='smartviews-app-list']/li[@data-id='simple-unread']")).click();
```

If still the code is not working for you, then the error might be somewhere else, and you have to post the code you have tried to figure out where the error is occuring.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with click method.
My solution was to create method focusOnElement()

```
private void focusOnElement(WebElement element) {
    new Actions(this.browserDriver).moveToElement(element).perform();
}

and then focus first before click:
  driverEx.focusOnElement("xpath");
  driverEx.findElement("xpath").click();
```